# upper density and density

Tags: limits, measure-theory

Assume $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. If $A$ has a non-zero density, then there exists a constant $n\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $A-n:=\{a-n\in\mathbb{N}|a\in A\}$ has non-zero **upper density**.

Any hints or ready to use theorem for this ?

P.s. density and upper density is defined as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1} {n}|A\cap[1,n]|$$
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1} {n}|A\cap[1,n]|$$